# Custom Http Handler in MVC 3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, httphandler, handlers, staticfilehandler

I'm using an Http Handler to localize javascript files used in my application:
see: [Localize text in JavaScript files in ASP.NET](http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx)

I want to use the handler provided so I did the following:

1) Ignored routes using this code in Global.asax - I have added the `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.js.axd/{*pathInfo}");` line of code to the `RegisterRoutes` method so it looks like this:

---

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.js.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

2) I have added `<add path="*.js.axd" verb="*"  type="CamelotShiftManagement.HttpHandlers.ScriptTranslator" />` line to my web.confing file in the Views folder so it looks like this:

---

```
<system.web>
   <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*.js.axd" verb="*"  type="CamelotShiftManagement.HttpHandlers.ScriptTranslator" />
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
   </httpHandlers>
```

And yet I get a *Page not found* error when I try to access the following URL:

```
http://camelotshiftmanagement.com/Scripts/Administration/OrganizationalStructure.js.axd
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

---

**Progress:**
Okay, so I found out an awkward mistake i made...
For some reason I thought that when adding a Handler for `*.js.axd` will find the file but actually it did not because the file was named `OrganizationalStructure.js` witout the `.axd` extension.
So that is the reason for the *404 error* but now i get a different error from the server and I need your help again.

accessing `http://camelotshiftmanagement.com/Scripts/Administration/OrganizationalStructure.js.axd` produced a different error this time: *404.17 The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.*

**Additional error information**

```
Server Error in Application "CAMELOTSHIFTMANAGEMENT.COM"
Internet Information Services 7.5
Error Summary
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

Detailed Error Information
Module:  "StaticFileModule"
Notification:  "ExecuteRequestHandler"
Handler:  "StaticFile"
Error Code:  "0x80070032"
Requested URL:  "http://camelotshiftmanagement.com:80/Scripts/Administration/OrganizationalStructure.js.axd"
Physical Path:  "C:\Code\CamelotShiftManagement\CamelotShiftManagement\Scripts\Administration\OrganizationalStructure.js.axd"
Logon Method:  "Anonymous"
Logon User:  "Anonymous"

Most likely causes:
The request matched a wildcard mime map. The request is mapped to the static file handler. If there were different pre-conditions, the request will map to a different handler.

Things you can try:
If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit MIME map.
```

Well I am way over my league here...
I do not understand why my custom handler is not called and instead a *StaticFile* handler is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay... so I did fix it (I think).

There were two problems:
1. the file name had a `.js` extention and not `.js.axd` as the handler needs.
2. I needed to register the handler to the IIS since it is a custom extension that is not recoginzed by default. 
To do that I added the following code under `<system.webServer>` node at the Main `Web.Config` file of my MVC application:

```
<handlers>
        <add name="CustomScriptHandler" path="*.js.axd" verb="*" type="CamelotShiftManagement.HttpHandlers.ScriptTranslator" />
</handlers>
```

*There is also a GUI process that can be done using the IIS Manager (7):
Open website node --> Handler Mapping --> Add Script Map*

No the correct handler is fired by the server and the code runs.

The only thing I am not sure of is that i still have to have a file with an `.js.axd` extention and a `.js` extension becuse the handler looks for the Javascript file to process and the server looks for a `.js.axd` file to start the custom handler.

If anyone have other insights, by all means do.